# VBA IE automation, To do events like displaying message,etc in excel when a link in webpage is clicked

Tags: vba, excel, webautomation

My requirement is i need to have a VBA code in excel which runs to do some action in excel when a link in webpage is clicked.For example when i click a link "login" in webpage my VBA code should press printscreen button in keyboard(like we use sendkeys).
I have been searching for this solution since two weeks over google but failed to get one.This is urgent project requirement, please save my day,thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please can you post what languages you are familiar with and I will refine my answer with more appropriate links. Particularly, are you familiar with .NET, C++, or VB6?

Comment: If you are doing this from a webbrowser control in a userform then it might just be possible to achieve what you want. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: I am familiar with all the languages you mentioned i just want a code wich can do some action when i click a link in webpage

Comment: @SiddharthRout i basically have a dynamic wbesite with 3 frames each ahving few  links in it

Comment: @RB hi thanks for your answer.but i found something like this ":Link.onclick = "snapshot" :snapshot is a function" but this is not working. i think its possible for VBA to identify if a link is clicked or not.

Comment: @nothingisimpossible Is the user using Internet Explorer to browse this webpage, or are they using a web-browser embedded in your Excel workbook? If they are using IE to browse, then it is not directly possible as per my answer. If they are using an embedded web-browser then it may be possible, but is not something I'm familiar with.

Comment: Similar question (with my answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877872/possible-to-intercept-onchange-event/12927960#12927960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an edited version of an answer I gave to a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877872/possible-to-intercept-onchange-event/12927960#12927960).

Project references set for "Microsoft HTML object library" and "Microsoft internet controls"

In a class module "clsEvents":

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents href As MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement

'Note that having defined "href" as "WithEvents", if you choose "href"
'  from the left-hand dropdown at the top of the class code module
'  then the right-hand dropdown will populate with events you can select
'  from to create an event-handling procedure in the class

Private Function href_onclick() As Boolean
    Debug.Print "link clicked"
    href_onclick = False 'cancels the navigation
End Function
```

In a regular module:

```
Option Explicit

Dim evt As clsEvents

Sub Setup()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim el2 As Object

    Set evt = New clsEvents

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~riggs/html/select_example.html"

    Do While IE.Busy
    Loop

    Set el2 = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(1)

    If Not el2 Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "setting event capture on link:" & el2.innerText
        Set evt.href = el2
    End If

End Sub
```

If you run the `Setup` sub and then click the "Javascript" link on the page in IE you should see output in the Immediate window of the VB editor.

Hope that helps get you started.

Comment: hi this worked wonderfully thank you very much, i have a modified version of this where i would click a key in keyboard and VBA does some action for me, but here i used while loop to achieve this, if i run it i am unable to access other XL files already opened because of Loop, can u provide me module same like this without loop..pls help me . i have done something like this

Comment: Sub test() 'eaEmlogin On Error Resume Next Do While ie.Visible = True If GetAsyncKeyState(44) Then wordapp.Selection.Paste End If If GetAsyncKeyState(19) Then MsgBox ("RESUME") End If If GetAsyncKeyState(35) Then Sheet1.timetaken.Value = Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss") save Exit Do End If Loop End Sub</code>

Comment: Why don't you start a new question with this?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing native you can do inside Internet Explorer to enable this functionality.

You would need to write an ActiveX control (using C#, C++, VB6, etc.), which would perform the Excel automation.

A few useful links:

- [How to automate Excel from VB6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219151)
- [How to write an updatable ActiveX control in VB6](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8249/How-to-write-an-updatable-ActiveX-control-for-web)